# Trying to concat 2 objects and destruct it into a new data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following objects:
obj1 - `{ min: 86, down: 95, up: 95, max: 88, … }`
obj2 - `{ right: 35 }`

I've written the following code:

```
Object.keys(response).forEach(key => {
  let newLabel = this.getLabel(key);
  let labelPanel = this.getPanel(key);
  let newPair = {
    [newLabel]: response[key]
  };
  let secondPair = {
    panel: labelPanel
  };
  const newObj = Object.assign(newPair, secondPair);
  newDataStructure = { ...newDataStructure,
    ...newObj
  };
});
```

And what I'm trying to do is to run over the given object, and create a new object with the updated key name.
For example:

```
min: 77  --->   Minimum: 77
```

I am also trying to get a value and set it to the 'panel' key, then I want to create a new object with these 2 keys, like this:
`{ Minimum: 99, panel: "Budget" }`

By doing this destructure:

```js
newDataStructure = { ...newDataStructure, ...newObj};
```

Result: I'm getting the new data structure like the following:

```
{Minimum: 99, panel: "Budget", down: 95, up: 95, max: 88,....}
```

Only the first part is getting the 'panel' key and value, but the rest are values from the 1st object.
How can I create an array of objects like this:

```
[{Minimum: 99, panel: "Budget"}, {Maximum: 88, panel: "Budget"}, {....}, {....}]
```

Comment: Can't you just do `{...newObj}` ? I don't understand the issue here

Comment: Oh okay I got it. You need to make an array first and then keep pushing your newObj in it. That should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an array first and then keep pushing your newObj in it. Try

```
let newResponse = [];
Object.keys(response).forEach(key => {
  let newLabel = this.getLabel(key);
  let labelPanel = this.getPanel(key);
  let newPair = {
    [newLabel]: response[key]
  };
  let secondPair = {
    panel: labelPanel
  };
  const newObj = Object.assign(newPair, secondPair);
  newResponse.push(newObj);
});
```

Comment: amazing, thanks. Was simpler than I thought.